# Exporting to csv: Romanian Language character failure

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, export-to-csv, diacritics

Helo I have a problem with diacritics .. in Mysql it's fine i set the utf8_general_ci  you cand see in this picture
[image]

in my website it's fine you can see

[image]

But when i export to csv file don't work.. 
Another file with diacritic reads my excel but this not.

[image]

I use this code for export

```
function doCsv(){

    var table = document.getElementById("exportTable").innerHTML;
    var data = table.replace(/<thead>/g,'').replace(/<\/thead>/g,'')
    .replace(/<tbody>/g,'').replace(/<\/tbody>/g,'')
    .replace(/<tr role="row" class="odd">/g,'').replace(/<tr role="row" class="even">/g,'').replace(/<\/tr>/g,'\r\n')
    .replace(/<th style="background-color:#6699ff;">/g,'').replace(/<\/th>/g,';')
    .replace(/<td>/g,'').replace(/<\/td>/g,';')
    .replace(/\t/g,'').replace(/\n/g,'');
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = "exportToCSV.csv";
    link.href = "data:application/csv," + escape(data);
    link.click();
```

And if i put the alert it keeps well see :

[image]

Anyone to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the `%u0218`?  That means that *something* is converting to Unicode.  You don't want that.  You want `utf8` (or `utf8mb4`).

Select the HEX from the table.  For these letters: `ĂÎŞŢÂ`, you should get this hex if it is properly encoded in UTF-8:  `C482 C38E C59E C5A2 C382`.  Note that each accented letter turns into 2 hex bytes.

Your second attempt came back with `Ä‚ÃŽÅžÅ¢Ã‚`, which is "Mojibake" for `ĂÎŞŢÂ`.  It's hex is `C384E2809AC383C5BDC385C5BEC385C2A2C383E2809A`.

I discuss Mojibake and point out what was done wrong in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) .

Somehow, your Excel code needs to say to export UTF-8, not unicode.

And your table must be `utf8`, not `latin1`.

And the import must declare that the data is `utf8`.